How to add auth token to automatically generated openapi code?
In my Blazor WebAssembly project i connected a external openapi api by adding a ServiceReference in VisualStudio. After that the client side code is generated automatically.
In my Programm.cs i did:
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomApi>(sp => new CustomApi(builder.Configuration["BaseUrl"], new HttpClient() { }));


this works fine if there is no authentication. For the authentication i wrote a custom AuthenticationStateProvider and store the jwt token in the localStorage.
How do i add the token to the Authentication-Header of the HttpClient?
There is nothing in the automatically generated code to manipulate the HttpClient before a request. Looks like that needs to be done here in the Programm.cs, but how can i access the local storage from Program.cs? It needs to be in a way that the token is added for every request, so that it doesn't use a expired token, but that is something Scoped should to.
Of course it would be easy to just inject a httpclient and do it all manually, but there should be a way to do it with the automatically generated code.

I think new HttpClient() { } is the problem your CustomApi should request the client from the Dependency Injection. And that HttpClient should handle your Authorisation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0

CustomApi is autogenerated code which VisualStudio builts using nswag. No clean way to change it.

found a solution. This works, but i don't like using the JSRuntime:
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomApi>(sp =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var jsRuntime = sp.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
    var token = jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", "authtoken").Result;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }

    return new CustomApi(builder.Configuration["BaseUrl"], httpClient);
});

